# how do I insert a horizontal rule between php Sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, formatting

I have no idea where to even start on this.  I have code that is selecting data and ordering it based off of two columns.

```
<?php // Query member data from the database and ready it for display
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT id, Name, Age, Rank, Ring, Time FROM competitors ORDER BY Time  ASC, Ring + 0 ASC");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
$name =$row1["Name"];
$age =$row1["Age"];
$rank=$row1["Rank"];
$ring1=$row1["Ring"];
$time1=$row1["Time"];
?>
```

it then displays the data and sorts is based off of the two columns

```
<?php echo $time1; echo $ring1; ?>
```

it will display something such as this (yes I know the code I posted doesn't actually display this, but its just a concept)

ring    time

1       10:00

1       10:00

1       10:00

1       11:00

1       11:00

1       11:00

I would like to know how I can make it insert a horizontal rule after the first sort by is completed.  so it would look something more like this:

1       10:00

1       10:00

1       10:00

---

1       11:00

1       11:00

1       11:00

and if there were any additional sorts, it would show after each sort is completed as well. 
Any advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the last `$time1` and when it changes, insert the `<hr>`

```
$lastTime = null;
while (/* whatever */) {
    // snip

    // check for null so as not to insert an <hr> for the first record
    if ($lastTime != null && $lastTime != $time1) {
        echo '<hr>';
    }
    $lastTime = $time1;

    // and so on
}
```